# Ubuntu 19.04 installed into WSL "Windows System for Linux" on Win10 host - How? Will it run Graphics intensive programs?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, windows-10, 19.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The current Windows Store App  "Ubuntu 18.04LTS" is just a "Terminal" version and less than 2gb.  It does not run graphic intensive applications (opengl) like OpenCPN and it does not have a graphic interface.

Is there a way to "upgrade" to the full version of Ubuntu 18.04LTS or install Ubuntu 19.04 on WSL? Will everything work?

See:

[Windows Subsystem for Linux Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)

[There's more to WSL than Ubuntu - Look at Rolling your own](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/theres-more-to-wsl-than-ubuntu/)

[Must Read: Microsoft Put a Real Linux Kernel Inside Windows 10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/05/ubuntu-support-windows-subsystem-linux-2)

[Microsoft Build 2019: Introducing WSL 2, the newest architecture for the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://hub.packtpub.com/microsoft-build-2019-introducing-wsl-2-the-newest-architecture-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/)
This is encouraging and it looks to me (ubuntu newbe) that WSL2 will run the full version of Ubuntu 19.04 provided that a Windows Store App is packaged. Is that correct?

[More Details On Microsoft's WSL2 Implementation For Running Linux Binaries On Windows 10](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=WSL2-Build-Conf-Video)

[Announcing WSL2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/)  - increase the file system performance, and make more apps work inside of WSL - run ELF64 Linux binaries on Windows - based on the source available at kernel.org. In initial builds we will ship version 4.19 of the kernel - This kernel has been specially tuned for WSL 2 - optimized for size and performance to give an amazing Linux experience on Windows - We will service this Linux kernel through Windows updates, which means you will get the latest security fixes and kernel improvements without needing to manage it yourself

---

It appears that this June there will be a new Windows Store app for Ubuntu 19.04 using [WSL2](https://hub.packtpub.com/microsoft-build-2019-introducing-wsl-2-the-newest-architecture-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/). However I believe this Store app is just for the "Windows Terminal" version and not the full version.  Just going to a Vbox install might be much easier?

Will I be able to install a full version of Ubuntu 18.04LTS or preferably Ubuntu 19.04 and run [OpenCPN](https://opencpn.org/) in WSL2 this June when Ubuntu 19.04 is available on the Windows Store?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run GUI apps, you need to run a Xserver like VcXsrv or X411. Then run `` export DISPLAY=`cat /etc/resolv.conf|grep nameserver|awk '{print $2}'`:0 ``

[Set your Xserver like this---To allow remote access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKHtq.png)

You can run any GUI apps now!

I haven't tried OpenCPN but Avogadro and CERN ROOT works great by this way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to "upgrade" to the full version of Ubuntu 18.04LTS or install Ubuntu 19.04 on WSL?

No. WSL is meant to have the many capabilities of the command line to the windows system.

> Will I be able to install a full version of Ubuntu 18.04LTS or preferably Ubuntu 19.04 and run OpenCPN in WSL2 this June when Ubuntu 19.04 is available on the Windows Store?

That's asking for conjecture. But I doubt it. Microsoft is not interested in having a desktop replacement for Windows.

> Just going to a Vbox install might be much easier?

If you want to play games on Windows then the order of preference should be:

- Dual boot
- Virtualbox. You need a more power for that. Good CPU. Good GPU. High memory

All the other methods suck compared to those 2 at so many levels it is not worth mentioning.

Comment: Not interested in games. Want to run OpenCPN. Regarding MS not wanting a desktop replacement, this sounds reasonable, but read links above about WSL2.

Comment: I think your suggestion to use Vbox is a a simpler more direct solution for now. Thanks.

Comment: opencpn has a PPA for Ubuntu: https://opencpn.org/wiki/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=opencpn:opencpn_user_manual:getting_started:opencpn_installation:ubuntu_ppa

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I've used the PPA once, after installing Windows Store Ubuntu 18.4LTS with WSL, which is just a "Terminal" version, when I execute "opencpn" I get gtk errors.